# make the linear transformation matrix invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with a one-dimensional null-space. Show that we can choose vectors $u,\,v\,$ so that the linear transformation $$B = A + u \otimes v^t$$ is invertible.  Here $u \otimes v^tx \overset{d} = \langle x, v \rangle$.

I totally have no ideas. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your operator $u\otimes v$ acts as
$$(u\otimes v)x = (v\cdot x)u,$$
it is sufficient to take

$$v\in \ker A,\quad v\ne 0\\
u\in \Bbb R^n,\quad u\notin im(A)$$